# Power apps button & dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, formula

I need to set up a dropdown selection based on a button trigger. If button not selected, dropdown must remain empty.

Could anyone assist?

Using following syntax on the dropdown:

```
If(button1.selected, dropdown1= "selection", "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this formula on **OnVisible** property of Screen:

```
UpdateContext({ddDefaultValue: ""})
```

Then set **Default** property of dropdown control to:

```
ddDefaultValue
```

Add below formula on **OnSelect** property of button:

```
UpdateContext({ddDefaultValue: "selection"})
```

For more information, refer: [Set Dropdown value with Button Click](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Set-Dropdown-value-with-Button-Click/td-p/638692)

---

**Update**:

Note that, if you are using a combo box control, trying to use only a variable, whether in `Default` or `DefaultSelectedItems`, will give you an error:

> There is an error in this formula. Try revising this formula and running it again.

In that case, you would have to set it in this way:

```
{Value: ddDefaultValue}
```

Comment: Can't just set the Default (or DefaultSelectedItems) property of the dropdown to a variable - it will give you an error: "There is an error in this formula. Try revising this formula and running it again." The link has this as something the OP already tried and failed at, not the solution.

Comment: I have tested it and it worked fine for me. It worked for OP as well and already marked as an answer. Which "link" are you talking about exactly? Maybe there is something wrong with how you set the variable and the data type of variable. Ask new question specific to your requirements mentioning those in details instead of downvoting working & accepted solutions.

Comment: @vapcguy Also, I think you are using combo box control and not the drop down control. As, DefaultSelectedItems property is not available for drop down control. Hence the structure and data type variable needs to be in different format for both the controls.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - it was a difference between the 2 controls. It won't let me take away the downvote until it's edited. I submitted one to say you must do `{Value: ddDefaultValue}` if it's a combo box, but still didn't unlock the vote-guess you have to do it. But I was talking about the link in the answer-what else would you have thought I was talking about?! They said they tried & failed with `UpdateContext({FormStatusValue: "New"});` in their button click event. So seemed odd `UpdateContext({ddDefaultValue: "selection"})` works when the OP in the link you had matched your answer & failed.

Comment: I have approved your edits now.

Comment: Thanks, removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you should notice:

1. There is no `Selected` property for [Button control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-button).

   As far as I know, you can only configure one-way action on one button control, there is no “release” or “unselect” status for it once the button is clicked, unless you reset `Button.OnSelect` from outside.

   You will need a second button if you want to clear the dropdown control value.
2. If you decide to use **UpdateContext** function (as the first Answer introduced), note that the default value should be set on the Choice column data card instead of the combo box (`DataCardValue2`)

   For example:

   `<ChoiceColumn>_DataCard.DefaultSelectedItems = { Value: ddDefaultValue }`

And you could update `ddDefaultValue` in the OnSelect of a button:

```
Set(ddDefaultValue,"My Dropdown Value")
```

In the App's OnStart:

```
Set(ddDefaultValue,"")
```

So it remains empty unless the button is clicked.